# Agregar columna de posiciones SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Tengo el siguiente condigo:

```
SELECT TERRITORIAL,
       REGIONAL,
       TOTAL,
       1 AS POSICION
FROM AR_TEST
```

Mi resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito hacer es que la columna posicion se este aumentando + 1 para obtener el número de la posicion de la region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias usar [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Editado, tal como comenta @Lamak, te cambiaria el orden, así que cambiamos el `order by`

```
 SELECT TERRITORIAL,
       REGIONAL,
       TOTAL,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 0)) AS POSICION
FROM AR_TEST
```

Deberia ser compatible con sql server **`2008+`**

Comment: Ojo que el criterio de orden para la posición no parece ser un orden alfabético de la columna `TERRITORIAL`. El op debería aclarar cómo quiere que se ordene

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TERRITORIAL,
       REGIONAL,
       TOTAL,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REGIONAL) as POSICION FROM AR_TEST
```